# Which version of Angular material datepicker do I have to use?

Tags: angular, datepicker

I'm developing an Angular 2 application using the Angular template of Visual Studio. For the web service I'm using ASP.NET Core 2. Here are the version of the packages I have installed:
[image]

I'm confuse because I'm new in Angular development and I think I know there are two versions of angular: AngularJS and Angular 2 (or Angular v.4.0).

I need to use a datepicker and I have found two datepickers:
[angular2-material-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-material-datepicker) with the import: 
`import { DatepickerModule } from 'angular2-material-datepicker'`.
And [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) with the import: 
`import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';`

I have added the last one to my project but I'm not sure which one do I have to use.

Which Datepicker do I have to use if I'm using Angular 2?

Comment: You just have 2 different datepickers. `MatDatepicker` is the [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), the other one is the one you linked to. Choose whichever one you really want to use.

Comment: @DGarvanski I don't understand this: *the other one is the one you linked to*. linked to where? In packages.json?

Comment: No, it's not that. I meant linked to in your question. `DatepickerModule` is from [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-material-datepicker) and `MatDatepickerModule` is from [this one](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview). As you can see - not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to Angular version, but rather to personal preference.

You have **AngularJS** which is basically Angular 1 : the main language for AngularJS is Javascript.

You also have **Angular**, which is Angular 2, or Angular 2+ (up to 5 now) : the main language for Angular is Typescript.

Both of the packages you found are Typescript : you cann see it with the import :

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
```

With AngularJS, there is no import, because your package manager handles the imports.

So, back to your question : you have 2 modules to chose from.

On one hand, you have `angular2-material-datepicker`, and on the other one, `@angular/material`. How must you chose ? Simple, actually :

- **Chose from what you prefer**. If you like the style of one of them, then chose it !
- **Chose it from what you need**. `@angular/material` is a very powerful library, but you might not use everything in it. If you only need a datepicker, then you should take the other one.
- **Chose it from the documentation**. Some packages are well documented, some others aren't. Take the package you're most comfortable with, especially if you start Angular.

A last word on my personal point of view : I recomment you take packages starting with `@angular` when you're given a choice. Because those packages, are maintained by the Angular team, meaning they're thought to work with Angular.

I hope this helped !

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot. I have another question: Am I using Angular 2?

Comment: ^^ I don't know, you privded no code. But seeing your imports, I think you might, yes. To test your application, are you running `ng serve` ?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio so I don't know if I'm running `ng serve`. My problem is that I can't find any info about if I'm using AngularJS or Angular2. There is a link when I create the project using the template, but it hasn't any info about which version of Angular. I have ran `ng serve` in a cmd and I get the error: `Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'`. So, don't worry, I will try to figure out which version I'm using.

Comment: Hum I see the issue. What you should do is 1 - install the CLI with `npm install -g @angular/cli` 2 - Once installed, run `ng new PROJECT_NAME` 3 - Wait for the commande to end, then run `cd PROJECT_NAME && ng serve`. This should make you a proper Angular (Not AngularJS) project, clean and ready to go !